# Uniform continuous distribution for cycles.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expectation, conditional-expectation

Let there be $n$ people standing in a circle and holding hands with probability $p$.

What is the expectation value $E(X)$ for the number of 'chains' when $p=.5$?

For what $p$ is $E(X)$ largest?

Edit: a chain is defined by two or more people next to one another holding hands.

Comment: If we allow chains of length one and call them "trains", then the number of trains is given by the number of neighbours that do not hold hands (unless everyone is holding hands), so there are about $n(1-p)$ trains. Since, on average, there are $n(1-p)^2$ trains of length one, I would expect that, on average, there are about $\color{red}{np(1-p)}$ chains.

Comment: If all the people are holding hands, (so a ring), does that count as 1 chain?

Comment: If you allow 1 person, then the number of 'trains' is simply the number of people not holding hands (as above) which is just a poisson distribution

Answer (score 0):

I made a short python script to run a monte carlo simulation on this.  In this, I assumed that if there was a ring (so everyone holds hands), then this would *not* be a chain.  One could do it the other way, but this way means that the number of chains can be counted by counting the number of substrings in the ring that are equal to $T,F$.

[image]

Under these conditions it looks like the peak is pretty much at $p=0.5$ for all $n$.  In fact the graph looks pretty much exactly like $np(p-1)$, like one of the commenters guessed.

The code, in case you're interested, is here:

```
#http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1359692/uniform-continuous-distribution-for-cycles

import pylab as py
import numpy as np

def noChains(hands):
    hands2 = np.zeros(hands.shape,dtype=bool)
    hands2[:,:-1] = hands[:,:-1] & np.logical_not(hands[:,1:])
    hands2[:,-1]  = hands[:,-1]  & np.logical_not(hands[:,0])
    return np.sum(hands2,axis=1)

fig = py.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)

noPs = 50        
ps = np.linspace(0,1,noPs).reshape((noPs,1))
reps = 10000

for n in [1,2,5,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100]:
    E = np.zeros(noPs)

    for i in range(reps):
        E += noChains(np.repeat(np.random.random(n).reshape((1,n)),noPs,axis=0)<=ps)
    E = E/reps
    ax1.plot(ps,E,"-")
    ax1.text(ps[25],E[25],"$n=%d$"%n)
    print(n,np.argmax(E),ps[np.argmax(E)],np.max(E))
ax1.set_title("$E(X)$ vs $p$ for various $n$")
ax1.set_xlabel("$p$")
ax1.set_ylabel("$E(X)$")
ax1.set_xlim(0.000000,1.000000)
ax1.set_ylim(0.000000,26.000000)


py.savefig("E vs p for n3.png")
```